# Can I change the Sender's name in an email already sent on an Exchange Server?

Tags: outlook, vsto, exchange-server

If I get an email from john.doe@aol.com and I want to change the sender's name to john@mydomain.com, how would I do it?

Could I modify the email that already resides on the server?

I do not want to forward the email... just change it in place.

I am happy with an app that connects to the exchange server and does it, or something that runs in my Outlook client that changes it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic guess, but you can try the following:

Get an imap based email account. If your exchange account also has imap then that should be fine as well. If it's an account different from the exchange account, you can copy that mail to the imap inbox folder. Use Thunderbird to add that account. Once you synchronise your IMAP account you should have the mail on your local hard drive (in your thunderbird profile folder). It's possible that you can edit it there and synchronise it back to your imap server. There, just move it back to your exchange account and you should have the mail with a different senders name. I didn't try that approach, but it should/could work.